# How to show a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I'm trying to show a popup when the mouse is over "a" element.

The problem is that I want to keep the popup when the mouse is over the popup element but the popup disappear when the mouse is over it.

The popup is just under the `<a>` element (on the display).

This is my code

HTML:

```
 <ul>
   <li>
    <a id="test">
      <div>
         Some text
      </div>

     <div id="popup">
        <ul>
          <li><a>text0</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>text1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li> TEXT
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
 #popup {
  display:none;
 }    

 #test:hover #popup {
   display:block;
 }
```

I tagged the question 'JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY' because if there is a solution with them, it would be welcome.

**EDIT**

**THIS IS ACTUALLY MY CODE, and it doesn't works**

Comment: Your code works just fine. #popup is a child of the anchor, as such you'll always be hovering it while on its child nodes.

Comment: Please provide us with all of your code. If there is anything you are leaving out, please put it in the question. It is difficult to post an answer to your problem if you continue to change the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #popup {
 display:none;
 }    
 a:hover + #popup {
   display:block;
 }
```

Try this should work.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vQ3j/1)

Comment: Updated the jsFiddle to make the changes.

Answer (score 3):

Before your start coding take a look at jQueryUI Tooltip (http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ ).
It does what you want with minimal programming requirements.

From the doku:

> Customizable, themeable tooltips, replacing native tooltips.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
  </script>
  <style>
  label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="#" title="That's what this widget is">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. When you hover
the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native tooltip.</p>
<p>But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with
<a href="http://themeroller.com" title="ThemeRoller: jQuery UI's theme builder application">ThemeRoller</a>
will also style tooltips accordingly.</p>
<p>Tooltips are also useful for form elements, to show some additional information in the context of each field.</p>
<p><label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes." /></p>
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That sure seems like a lot of work to make a simple div active. Why not keep it simple with a simple css statement?

Comment: $( document ).tooltip();? How is this a lot of work and not simple?

Comment: It requires embedding two javascript libraries and stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

This will keep the popup active while the user is hovering it if the element is not related, otherwise if its a child of the element it won't lose focus.

```
#popup:hover {
  display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanna make a nice popup use this:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking to use jQuery, you can make the div a child of the a tag and use some css trickery to make it all work (http://jsfiddle.net/TMBGm/):

```
<a>some text<div>popup text</div></a>


a {
    position: relative;
}
a div {
    display: none;
}
a:hover div {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: In the CSS in your example, you're missing the position portion, which  is rather crucial.  You also need to remember to have your div overlap the a's content, so you might need to make adjustments such as `top: 10px;` to position it where you want it

Comment: the popup is in position:absolute, and It doesn't event show the popup. When I look in my firfox developper tools, I see that there is 2 <a> element ?????? I don't know why... And I see that the popup isn't inside the 1st <a> element...

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is... I've copied the html and css you provided into jsfiddle and it seems to work (http://jsfiddle.net/Bkvam/)  Is there something missing from that?

Comment: The issue turns out to be that your HTML is invalid.  If you remove the anchor tag from the wrapping list item, it works

Answer (score 0):

The adjacent sibling selector is perfect for this example:

```
div {
    display: none;
}

a:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G4hd9/

Article: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Your original code seems to work fine after you edited the question: http://jsfiddle.net/G4hd9/1/

Comment: Ok, you need to use #test:hover + #popup {} instead of #test:hover  #popup {}. This is your fiddle with a '+' added: http://jsfiddle.net/pNPPJ/

Comment: It doesn't keep the popup if mouse is over it... I have solve the problem by change <a> to <div>. thanks you very much anyway :)